# What the difference between a += b and a = a + b with different types a and b

Tags: java, types

For example, I have this code :

```
int a = 2;
long b = 3;
a = a + b;//Error while compilation
a += b;//Normaly fineshes
```

What is the difference between the two instructions , because I saw such questions in list of interview questions?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int. Did u check this ?

Comment: when you perform a+b, it must meet the type checking condition. When you do a += b, it will implicitly do the addition.